# How to get a file path from a ProjectItem via the FileNames property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, envdte

I'm trying to extract the file name from a `ProjectItem` and already found out a few things:

- Using `projectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.ToString()` will sometimes fail, namely with HTML files.
- Using `projectItem.FileNames[0]` seemed to be the solution, it worked for all types of files inside projects.

But when trying to get a file path from a solution file (a file that is saved directly in a solution folder, not inside a project), the call failed with an `ArgumentException`. Some more investigation and trial-and-error later I seem to have found the cause: For solution files the `FileNames` property is 1-based, not 0-based. Now I'm completely lost and fail to see the system behind all this. My current solution is:

1. Check if the `Kind` of the project item is equal to `VSConstants.GUID_ItemType_PhysicalFile` (then it is a "regular" file). If yes, return `projectItem.FileNames[0]`.
2. In all other cases return `projectItem.FileNames[1]`.

   ```
   var projItemGuid = new Guid(projectItem.Kind);
   try
   {
       return (projItemGuid == VSConstants.GUID_ItemType_PhysicalFile)
           ? projectItem.FileNames[0]
           : projectItem.FileNames[1];
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       throw new FileNotFoundException(
           $"The file path of {projectItem.Name} could not be retrieved" +
           $"\nThe index might be wrong.) \nOriginal exception: {e.Message}");
   }
   ```

Is this exhaustive or am I missing something? Is getting a file name from a `ProjectItem` really this annoying and unsafe?

Comment: Yes, getting the file name is fragile and requires some exception handling

Comment: Do you know which exceptions I can expect or what best practices are to safely get the file path?

Comment: I just catch all exceptions, because you can't anticipate what a project implementation may throw. For example, for SQL Server Reporting Services the index is 0-based, not 1-based as usual for most projects.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I added my code in the question to illustrate my current solution.